# How can I add the path to torch to a Pybind11 extension?

Tags: python, c++, python-packaging, pybind11

I'm writing a python extension in C++ using pybind11 and I'm trying to make the `setup.py` file and this is what I have so far:

```py
from glob import glob

import setuptools

from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension(
        "my_ext",
        sorted(glob("src/my_ext/**/*.cc")),
    )
]


setuptools.setup(
    name="my_ext",
    version="0.1",
    package_dir={"": "src/my_ext/python/"},
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

However, when I run `pip install .`, I get this error:

```
In file included from src/my_ext/cc/thing.cc:7:
      src/my_ext/cc/thing.h:9:10: fatal error: 'torch/torch.h' file not found
      #include <torch/torch.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

Is there any argument I can pass to Pybind11Extension to allow it to find torch and build successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. Just needed to use some of pytorch's helper functions and look at `torch.utils.cpp_extension.CppExtension` for guidance:

```py
import os
from glob import glob

import setuptools
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import include_paths, library_paths

include_dirs = include_paths()
torch_library_paths = library_paths()
libraries = ["c10", "torch", "torch_cpu", "torch_python"]

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension(
        "my_ext",
        sorted(glob("src/my_ext/**/*.cc")),
        include_dirs=include_dirs,
        libraries=libraries,
        library_dirs=torch_library_paths,
    )
]


setuptools.setup(
    name="my_ext",
    version="0.1",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```